# Code disappearing when switching query on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an annoying problem with SQL server 2016. It's not really bad, just annoying. So when I'm switching query windows or even reducing the window of SQL server and I come back on one:

- The code can disappear
- Random color appear either on the code and hide it

I have to scroll to make it disappear and let the code appear.

Have someone already experienced that?

[image: Pics]

[image: Pics]

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server Management Studio? What SSMS version are you running? The latest as of this writing is 17.1.

Comment: Yes this is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an identified bug in SSMS per http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/533311/display-corruption-on-ssms-at-large-resolutions-on-second-screen

No workarounds have been identified.

Comment: I just started getting this error on a new build. The link in the answer has been taken down and I am trying to find this document on ANY of Microsofts support pages. Does anyone know of an update to this? It's killing my productivity!