# SSMS Display corruption switching tabs or executing scripts

Tags: ssms, highdpi

This is the same issue raised by this question: [Code disappearing when switching query on SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544110/code-disappearing-when-switching-query-on-sql-server/44544310#44544310)

Here is what it looks like: 
[image]
Unfortunately, it is occurring in the latest version of Windows 10 and SSMS 17.9.1.

It also blanks random parts of the menus: [image]

I have my video drivers updated (RTX2070 with default NVidia drivers). Nothing is over-clocked. I have installed, uninstalled, and reinstalled SSMS.

I have gone through all of the shortcut display compatibility settings and nothing corrects the issue. I also have display scaling turned off. This occurs on all three monitors 2560 x 1440, 3440 x 1440, 2560 x 1440.

One interesting observation more. If I am running SSMS in an RDP session on this machine the display error does not occur.

The reason I am posting what is basically a refresh / duplicate to an answered question is that Microsoft has taken down the link marked as an answer. Does anyone have current information regarding this bug?